# Error 104 after creating domain in Interbase 2020 script

Tags: sql, interbase

I am a beginner with Interbase (always used Advantage and SQL Server) and I am now running into a problem that is probably very easy to fix, but I'm just not seeing it (nor can I find a usable hint in the documentation).  Please consider the following (condensed script):

```
CREATE DOMAIN DOM_ID AS INTEGER;
CREATE TABLE Relatie (
  ID DOM_ID NOT NULL,
  RelatieNaam VARCHAR(100),
  Bedrijf VARCHAR(40),
  CONSTRAINT PK_RELATIE PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

This script fails (using 'Prepare') with error message '*Dynamic SQL error. SQL Error code = -104. Token unknown - line 2, char 1 CREATE*'.

I first thought creating the domain requires a `Commit` but as per documentation that's not required here since it's a DDL statement.

What am I doing wrong / am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this but looks like you are having problem with first CREATE.

And when I search found this link. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Creating_a_Domain

As I see there are additional lines with "EXEC SQL" before and "COMMIT;" after CREATE DOMAIN.

Also, it is written: "Once a domain is **defined** and **committed**, it can be used in CREATE TABLE statements to define columns."

Hope this helps.

Comment: For some reason, it can't be done in a single script (??). Creating the domain first and then creating the table (i.e. running two interactive SQL's) works.  Placing EXEC SQL before the CREATE DOMAIN or COMMIT thereafter, results in the same error message ('Token unknown'). Moreover, ANYTHING after the CREATE DOMAIN statement (CREATE, COMMIT, etc.) results in this error.  Very strange. I would think it's possible to build a single SQL script to generate all database objects in one pass....

Comment: Did you tried with "EXEC SQL" statments?

Comment: Yes, same error... The Interactive SQL window (IB Console) does not recognize it, before or after the CREATE DOMAIN statement.

Comment: What about this line "ID DOM_ID NOT NULL,"? Are you sure usage of ID, I could not find that. https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/CREATE_TABLE

Comment: ID would be the fieldname. Not sure what you're asking here...

Comment: OK, if it is acceptable name, no questions.